# jQuery - datepicker.parseDate on 'mm/y' causing Invalid Date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a validate method which seems pretty simple because I use something very similar when using the format `mm/dd/yy`, but when I use `mm/y`...I keep getting an invalid date.

Here is my validation:

```
function validateDate(dateField) {
    try{
        $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/y', dateField, null);
    }
    catch(error){
        alert(error);
    }
}
```

If I pass in a date like `05/11`...this logic complains that the date is invalid.  If I change the format to `mm/dd/yy` and enter `05/11/2011`...then it says it is valid.

Am I missing something when trying to validate a `mm/y` pattern?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, you need to supply at least a month and day for the datepicker to parse your date properly. If you leave the year out, it defaults to the current year, so parsing "06/15" as "dd/mm" will give you 2011-06-15. But if either month or day are omitted, they default to -1 and will produce an invalid date.

EDIT:

If you are just trying to confirm that the user entered a valid month and year, do this:

```
$.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/y', "01/" + dateField, null);
```