# jQuery datapicker parsing date throws invalid date exception

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

Why does this `$.datepicker.parseDate("mm/yy","02/2008");` throw an InvalidDate exception?

Comment: 02/2008 isn´t a complete date. Try 01/02/2008

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956766/jquery-datepicker-parsedate-on-mm-y-causing-invalid-date - I would point you to this question. The datepicker requires a day and a month atleast

Comment: @Oliver, just in case you ever need to know, each y represents two digits of an year in the date format of jQuery's datepicker. So just one y would mean "08" would be a valid year.

Comment: @webdreamer That's interesting, it is a little non-standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because in javascript a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object must have a day as well. You could fake the day to 01 by concatenating it to the string you are trying to parse:

```
var date = $.datepicker.parseDate("mm/yy/dd", "02/2008" + "/01");
```

Comment: The thing is I'm trying to imlement the month selector data picker by adapting jQuery's datapicker(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079525/jquery-datetime-picker-need-to-pick-month-and-year-only), and I don't actually know the format; all I know is that it won't have the day. But, from your answer I was able to do var date = $.datepicker.parseDate(format+"/dd",date + "/01"); Just leaving this here for future reference.

Comment: @webdreamer, that's exactly what I was suggesting. That's why I deliberately split the 2 strings in my answer as I thought that the first part is variable.

Answer (score 1):

It's because "02/2008" isn't a valid date, and cannot be converted into one by javascript.

You need to pass a string in a format which includes at least a day, month and year. See the [examples](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/%24.datepicker.parseDate) for more info.